# Is there a good real world example for coroutines

Tags: c++-coroutine

Currently I am reading a lot about coroutines. 
While I think I only partly understand what they do (Allowing a function to be returned and continued at a certain point for instance), I really don't know why I should use them. I see no real benefit in using a coroutine. For me these things look to me like goto with extra steps. Could someone give me a good real world example where a coroutine might really improve a code base? Maybe that helps me to get the concept.

Comment: You can implement generators with them, for example https://kirit.com/How%20C%2B%2B%20coroutines%20work.

Comment: @Artur Biesiadowski Thank you for the answer but where is the benefit over making int number static and continuing where the counter ended on the last call? (I already found that example)

Comment: Having static int won't work very well if you have more than one instance of generator and use them from different threads for example.

Comment: I could give the generator a template id (I don't want to annoy you, but that are the thougts I made which make it hard for me to see a benefit...)

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines allow us to model [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking) systems in a very **simple** and **modular** way. This kind of systems may suit many problems like multi-agent games, stock market simulators, operating systems, etc.

The **simplicity** comes from the fact that we may need only two function-like coroutines to express the concept in code. Classes, state structures, function pointers are no longer required. Below is a pseudo-code illustration which defines a `scheduler` and a `task`. Unlike normal functions, both instances of `task` pass the execution to each other after `do_one_step` call.

```
void scheduler(list<task> tasks) {
   while(true) {
     for(t : tasks)
       await t;
   }
}

void task(int arg) {
   while(1) {
     do_one_step(arg);
     yield;
   }
}

void main() { await scheduler( list( { task(0), task(1) } ); }
```

More importantly, the code for `task` may now be **modular**: tasks are allowed to include subtasks, which resemble its structure. Any subtask may be designed as a valid task itself:

```
void subtask(int arg) {
  do_one_step(arg);
  yield;
  do_one_step(arg);
  yield;
}

void task(int arg) {
   while(1) {
     await subtask(arg);
     yield;
   }
}

void main() { await scheduler( list({task(0), task(1), subtask(2)}); }
```

Coroutines allow us to stack subtasks into larger tasks, and provide us with a new tool to modularize our solutions.